# How to validate data graph expressed in json-ld version 1.1 with SHACL?

Tags: json-ld, validation, python, semantic-web, rdfa

I've currently tried using the python library pySHACL to validate them. It works if I do not have version 1.1 specific things in it's context.

For example, to validate this data graph:

```
{
    "@context": {
        "@version": 1.1,
        "@vocab": "http://schema.org/",
        "reproterms": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sanuann/schema-standardization/master/terms/",
        "reproschema": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sanuann/schema-standardization/master/schemas/",
        "preamble": {
            "@id": "reproterms:preamble",
            "@container": "@language"
        }
    },
    "@id": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sanuann/schema-standardization/master/activities/PHQ-9/phq9_schema",
    "@type": "reproschema:Activity",
    "preamble": 123
}
```

I have written a SHACL shape graph:

```
@prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .
@prefix schema: <http://schema.org/> .
@prefix sh: <http://www.w3.org/ns/shacl#> .
@prefix xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> .
@prefix dash: <http://datashapes.org/dash#> .
@prefix reproterms: <https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sanuann/schema-standardization/master/terms/> .
@prefix reproschema: <https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sanuann/schema-standardization/master/schemas/> .
schema:ActivityShape
    a sh:NodeShape ;
    sh:targetClass reproschema:Activity ;
    sh:property [
        sh:path reproterms:preamble;
        sh:datatype xsd:string ;
        sh:maxCount 1 ;
    ] .
```

This works when the `@version: 1.1` is removed from context of the data graph but throws error otherwise. (I use PySHACL to validate).
How do I validate the data graph without removing the version key?